# Common nginx configuration

Tags: nginx, configuration, automation, webserver, chef-infra

I have 4 environments.

1. Development
2. Quality
3. Testing
4. Production

Each environment has the same same nginx.conf and conf.d/* configurations.
We roll out each of these confs using chef individually on each environments. Making chef changes, uploading the cookbook and then running chef-client individually on each environment. Hence, 5X the effort.

The reason we do this is because we don't wanna risk the changes in production before first testing on all the 4 environments before it.

I would like to know a process by which I can deploy the changes on all environments in one go.

I am thinking something along the lines of a Jenkins job in a deploy pipeline based job.

Comment: I think the question is how do you want your pipeline to validate that something is ready for production? The short answer is yes -  a jenkins pipeline could handle the process, but you will need to write some tests so jenkins knows its allowed to move to the next stage of the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I mean basically you are describing a high-level CI/CD process. But there's a ton of options in that space. A toooooon. Jenkins is the grand-daddy and is still a very solid option, but if want something with deeper Chef integration there is Chef Automate. Or stuff like Concourse, GitLab CI, Codeship, etc. Unfortunately the specifics are up to you and your team.